# Ubuntu 14.10 : Wifi does not work after suspend

Tags: wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 14.10 as a dual boot with Windows 7. 
It seems to work fine, except when I suspend Ubuntu 14.10 and then resume, I cannot connect to WiFi networks (the computer cannot seem to detect any). When I restart the computer, it can connect again. 
Is there any solution to this problem? I would like to use Ubuntu without having to completely shut down every time.

I've tried to look up solutions, the only one I found was to type this into terminal

```
sudo killall NetworkManager
```

But this does not do anything.

In case it helps, my WiFi PCI card is a tp-link TL-WN951N.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

this will restart your network manager and you will be able to connect to the wifi.